# jqxgrid aggregates 'sum' ,replace dollar to an other symbol

Tags: jquery, jqxgrid

I used jqxgrid of jqwidgets, everything works well, but when I use aggregates  for a special
column which was used to statistics Total cost, I want to replace the `$` that in front of the number to an other symbol, I searched for a long time on google, but I still not fixed this problem.
Who can help me?
Thanks in advance

Here is a piece of girds' snapshot:

[image]

Comment: I solved this problem use FireBug,the log display the value is a string starts with '$',so just do value.replace(/^\$/,sth)

Answer (score 0):

Get this script,

```
var getLocalization = function () {
    var localizationobj = {};                
    localizationobj.currencysymbol = "your symbol ";                
    return localizationobj;
}
```

then during grid initialization:

```
    $("#jqxgriddata").jqxGrid(
    {
        width: 850,
        height: 250,
        localization: getLocalization(),
...
...
}
```

Hope this help,
JMS

Comment: thank you  JMS, I fixed the problem by value.replace(/^\$/,symbol) :)